# How to return a constructor argument value from a getter function in ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Example:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {

  }

  get name() {
    return /* “name” argument from constructor */;    
  }
}
```

I would like that the `name` getter returns the `name` value passed in to the constructor.

Comment: You cannot. Constructor parameters are still scoped to the constructor function, there's nothing in ES6 that changes this.

Answer (score 3):

Save the argument to an instance property:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name_ = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.name_;
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/joruyo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: If I’m going to use an intermediate variable, it’s probably better to set a symbol property, but I was hoping for a direct solution.

Comment: Yes, I posted the simplest answer to avoid unnecessary over-engineering. You can use symbols or WeakMaps to try to simulate private variables, but in the end it all boils down to "If it is not documented in the public API, use it at your own risk".

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
      get() {
        return name;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

That should do it :) (Not pretty but, will do)

You could make a helper function:

```
function makeGetter(obj, prop, value) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
    return value;
  });
}

class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    makeGetter(this, 'name', name);
  }
}
```

**Update:**

All you actually need is the following (can't believe I overcomplicated it):

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
var p = new Person('Edwin');
p.name; // returns 'Edwin'

p.name = 'Sime'; // Sets name
p.name; // returns 'Sime'
```

Comment: This reminds me, why didn’t ES6 give us sugar syntax for defining getters on objects? That `Object.defineProperty()` thing is just too low-level.

Comment: I don't know, but you could propose on `ES-Discuss`

Comment: TC39 have probably already spent 10 hours discussing proposals and couldn’t agree on anything :)

Comment: Regarding the update, that will make the property writable.